# LWC + Bootstrap Datepicker: issue trying to refresh the calendar UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, jquery, bootstrap

I got a request to disable some dates on the date picker and reload it when a certain field is changed.
Disable certain dates is not possible with lightning input. So I've implemented it on Bootstrap Datepicker.
I'm able to select the date properly. But disable dates depends on another field from the parent component called Event Type. For instance, when the user selects the "private" value on the Event Type dropdown, the calendar must enable just the Sunday days. When "company" is selected, it enables Thu, Fri, and Saturday days, and so on.

**The issue**:
When I change the Event Type field, I recall the same function that sets the date picker on the LWC child.js for the first time. But at this moment, Chrome Console logs Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function throws at https://acceptance-foxtrail.cs88.force.com/auraFW/javascript/hXQ6H-x_YQB1RZ2gyQB4Mg/aura_prod.js:21:29238.

Following a video where I explain better the issue:
https://youtu.be/Q0_ZiMxcvUA

Parent.**html**

```
<template>
<c-group-booking-page-event-type-selector
  oneventtypechange={handleEventTypeChange}>
</c-group-booking-page-event-type-selector>


<c-group-booking-page-date-picker 
    event={selectedEventTypeObject}
    ondatechange={handleDatepicker}>
</c-group-booking-page-date-picker>
</template>
```

Parent.**js**

```
export default class GroupBookingPageForm extends LightningElement {
@track selectedEventTypeObject;
    
handleEventTypeChange(event) {
   this.selectedEventTypeObject = event.detail;
   this.reRenderDatePicker();  
}

  reRenderDatePicker() {
    let datePickerComponent = this.template.querySelector('c-group-booking-page-date-picker');
    if (datePickerComponent) {
      datePickerComponent.setDatepicker();
  }
}
```

Child.**html**

```
<template>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input lwc:dom="manual" class="datepicker" onchange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Child.**js**

```
import { api, LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import resources from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/GroupBooking_DatePicker';

export default class GroupBookingPageDatePicker extends LightningElement {
    @track isJsLoaded = false;
    @api event;
    @api eventDate;

    @api
    renderedCallback() {

        if (!this.isJsLoaded) {
            this.isJsLoaded = true;
            this.eventDate = this.eventDate? this.eventDate : new Date();
    
            loadScript(this, resources + '/jquery.js')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('jquery.js loaded successfully.');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('An error occurred when attempted to load Datepicker jquery.js: ' + error);
            });
    
            loadScript(this, resources + '/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('bootstrap.js loaded successfully.');
                this.setDatepicker();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('An error occurred when attempted to load bootstrap.js: ' + error);
            });
    
            loadStyle(this, resources + '/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('css loaded successfully.');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('An error occurred when attempted to load css: ' + error);
            });
        }
    }

    @api
    setDatepicker() {
        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
            var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
            date.setDate(date.getUTCDate() + days);
            return date;
        }
        var self = this;
        let finalDate = new Date(new Date().getUTCFullYear(), 12-1, 31).addDays(365);
        var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
        var eventDate = self.eventDate? self.eventDate : new Date();
        var cont = self.event.minimumLeadtime? self.event.minimumLeadtime : 0;
        var disabledDates = [];
        var allDatesFromEventDateToNextYear = self.getDates(finalDate);
        
        allDatesFromEventDateToNextYear.forEach(d => {
            let matchDate = self.event.weekDaysAvailable.some(w => w === dayNames[d.getDay()]);
            if (!matchDate) {
                disabledDates.push(self.formatDate(d));
            }
        });
        
        while(cont != 0) {
            let d = self.formatDate(eventDate.addDays(cont))
            disabledDates.push(d);
            cont--;
        }
        
        $(self.template.querySelector('.datepicker')).datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: finalDate,
            datesDisabled: disabledDates
        })
        .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            self.selectedDate = selected.target.value;
            let dateval = self.selectedDate;
            const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("datechange", {
                    detail: dateval
                });
            self.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
        });
    }

    getDates(finalDate) {
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var currentDate = new Date();
        while (currentDate <= finalDate) {
            dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
        }
        return dateArray;
    }

    formatDate(date) {
        let day = date.getUTCDate() > 9? date.getUTCDate() : '0' + date.getUTCDate();
        let month = date.getUTCMonth() > 9? (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) : '0' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        let year = date.getUTCFullYear();
        return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mario, welcome to sfse! Generally locker service doesn't play nicely with other frameworks, this one has dependencies on jQuery and bootstrap. Full calendar is recommended and might be better as it doesn't has a dependencies with jQuery.

Comment: Hi, Raul. Thx! So, I've been trying to use jQuery and Bootstrap because I've seen people using it with LWC as well. I don't know FullCalendar yet, and since this task is very time-sensitive, I will prefer to find out a solution, if it's possible. Taking advantage, could you help me, pls? :D What I need is just to bring again the datepicker.js so that I can refresh the calendar ui after change the Event Type field value. Thank you in advance!